# Sort entities in query by reverse order of creation w/o timestamp. GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

We use GAE w Java and JDO 2.3.
Is there way to sort entities of JDO query in reverse of creation order?
I think that if we will use index columns instead of timestamp it will increase performance. Is it right?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can't rely on ids to be continuously allocated by the datastore service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on ids to be continuously allocated by the datastore service.

But you can either set a timestamp as part of your keyname, or allocate a continuous id range using [`DatastoreService.allocateIds`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28java.lang.String,%20long%29), to ensure your keys monotonically increasing.

You should then be able to sort the entities key using [`KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity#KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY).

Compared to an indexed timestamp property, you would would save the additional index lookup if you are querying the full entities, but it would make no different for `key only` queries.

Note that a descending sort order will require an additional index as described in the [App Engine JDO Query documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Queries_on_Keys)

Also beware of [hot tablet](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) issues if you have a high write-throughput of entities with monotonically keys or indexes.

Comment: Yes, but are they strictly consecutive? I have personally seen id's generated in this order 1001, 2001, 2002, 1002, etc.. It seems that frontend instances get ID blocks and then allocate from this blocks. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a query and sorting on a single timestamp column appengine will create an index for you and the query will be very fast.